# vscode is not catching MODULE_NOT_FOUND error

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

[image]

As you see the code and file structures in the image above, I have not run `npm init -y` or `npm install express`. Because of that, I have MODULE_NOT_FOUND error. My question is why VSCode is not catching this error. I think it used to display a red line for undefined dependency.  What I found was that VSCode tried to refer to this file: `~/.cache/typescript/4.6/node_modules/@types/express/index`.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue so that it only refers to the node_modules folder in its directory (and indicates an error if it has not found one)?

I have mistakenly run `npm init -y` on my home `~` directory and removed package.json from my root folder. Is there any chance that this might cause this issue?

Comment: You're running app.js but the file is called index.js

Comment: _"how to fix this issue so that it only refers to the node_modules folder in its directory"_... create a `package.json` file so it knows you're working with a Node project